# Tab widget in android from portrait to landscape

Tags: android, tabwidget

Is there any way in order to make a single layout for tab widjets and when changing orientation from portrait to lanscape single layout is called.

Which properties and how the properties are changed.

Answer (score 0):

Just create the layout and android will do the rest is the simple answer.  See the [Tab Widget Layout tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) on the on the Android developers site for a code example.  It handles correctly with both portrait and landscape orientations.